# filter one dataframe via conditions in another

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to recursively filter a dataframe, `d` by an arbitrary number of conditions (represented as rows in another dataframe `z`).

I begin with a dataframe `d`:

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = letters[1:10])
```

The second dataframe `z`, has columns `x1` and `x2`, which are lower and upper limits to filter `d$x`. This dataframe `z` may grow to be an arbitrary number of rows long.

```
z <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,3,8), x2 = c(1,4,10))
```

I want to return all rows of `d` for which `d$x <= z$x1[i]` and `d$x >= z$x2[i]` for all `i`, where `i = nrow(z)`.

So for this toy example, exclude everything from 1:1, 3:4, 8:10, inclusive.

```
   x  y
2  2  b 
5  5  e
6  6  f
7  7  g
```

Comment: Why is `x=2` included? It doesn't match your constraints.

Comment: It does match the constraints. Each row in `z` is a pair of constraints. So exclude everything from 1:1, 3:4, 8:10, inclusive.

Comment: So your last frame is the rows to exclude? Sorry, I must have missed that.

Comment: Hmm, you're absolutely right. I can make that clearer in the problem statement.

Comment: What you're talking about is a non-equi join, and currently the only way (in R) to do that efficiently is using `data.table`. I think akrun is trying to get to a good solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a sequence between `x1` and `x2` values and use `anti_join` to select rows from `d` that are not present in `z`.

```
library(tidyverse)

remove <- z %>%
  mutate(x = map2(x1, x2, seq)) %>%
  unnest(x) %>%
  select(x)

anti_join(d, remove)

#  x y
#1 2 b
#2 5 e
#3 6 f
#4 7 g
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a non-equi join

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(d)[z, .I, on = .(x >=x1, x <= x2), by = .EACHI]$I
i1
#[1]  1  3  4  8  9 10
d[i1]
#    x y
#1:  1 a
#2:  3 c
#3:  4 d
#4:  8 h
#5:  9 i
#6: 10 j
d[!i1]
#   x y
#1: 2 b
#2: 5 e
#3: 6 f
#4: 7 g
```

---

Or using `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
fuzzy_inner_join(d, z, by = c('x' = 'x1', 'x' = 'x2'),
        match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)) %>% 
     select(names(d))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#      x y    
#  <int> <fct>
#1     1 a    
#2     3 c    
#3     4 d    
#4     8 h    
#5     9 i    
#6    10 j
```

Or to get the rows not in 'x' from 'd'

```
fuzzy_anti_join(d, z, by = c('x' = 'x1', 'x' = 'x2'),
        match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)) %>% 
     select(names(d))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#      x y    
#  <int> <fct>
#1     2 b    
#2     5 e    
#3     6 f    
#4     7 g
```

Comment: The non-equi join approach works, but the fuzzyjoin doesn't quite return the expected result.

Comment: @RichPauloo I showed two methods and both of them work for me.

Comment: @RichPauloo anyway, if you have mentioned only based on tidyverse, could have created that.  Th

Comment: @RichPauloo if you meant for `anti_join`, it is `fuzzy_anti_join`.  anyway,